# Spring Form Submission

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a simple spring form. But some how i am getting 404 error.

Here is my Form

```
        <form:form method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="user" >
            <form:label path="userName">User Name</form:label>
            <form:input path="userName"/>
            <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
            <form:password path="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form:form>
```

My Controller for the above form

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        if(user.getUserName().equals("raju") && user.getPassword().equals("pass")){
            return new ModelAndView("success");
        }
        return new ModelAndView("failure");
    }
}
```

When i submit the form, the control is not coming into the LoginController. My Home url is `http://localhost:8080/WebAppl`. When i submit the form url is `http://localhost:8080/login`

Any idea where i am doing wrong ? Inputs appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it obvious the context path is missing?

Comment: Yes Bart. Context path is missing when i submit the form. I don't know how to solve this issue. Can u please suggest

Comment: It's a simple as adding the missing context path to the action attribute.

Comment: Thank you Bart, It worked after changing the action attribute to WebAppl/login. But isn't it tedious to give the full url all the time. Do we have any alternative for this.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the spring taglib and call `<spring:url value="/login" />` or you can add it manually using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead and see whether the error still exist or not :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPageRenderer(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    return "login-page";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        if(user.getUserName().equals("raju") && user.getPassword().equals("pass")){
                model.addAttribute("success", true);
                return "success";
        }
        model.addAttribute("failure", true);
        return "failure";
}


<form:form commandName="user" method="post">
   <form:label path="userName">User Name</form:label>
   <form:input path="userName"/>
   <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
   <form:password path="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error 404, is page not fond error. You are missing path content path in xml file.
Here is the simple of web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

    </web-app>

And here is dispatcher-servlet.xml

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.sample" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```